# How to access the value of field through a many to many relationship using dot notation?

Tags: django, django-models

A Pizza has toppings, a topping has a manufacturer, and a manufacturer has a name. Let's assume the same manufacturer creates all the toppings.

I'm able to get the value of the manufacturer from a query like this:

```
pizza.toppings.all()[0].manufacturer.name
```

This is based upon models like this:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)

class Topping(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

However the `all()[0]` in the query seems ugly. Is there any way to rewrite the above query so it looks something like this:

```
pizza.toppings.manufacturer.name
```

I understand there are multiple toppings so the query can't be so simple, but `all()[0]` seems horrible.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

If the same manufacturer creates all toppings, put `manufacturer` relation in `Pizza` model. So you can access it like `pizza.manufacturer.name`

Update (Since you said that you can't change the model) :

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ManyToManyField(Topping) # this should be called toppings, not pizza

    @cached_property
    def manufacturer(self):
        topping = self.pizza.toppings.first()
        if topping:
            return topping.manufacturer
```

Now you can access it like `pizza.manufacturer`

Comment: Sorry I can't change the models. I am simplifying the question so it is easier to understand. The question is how can I go obj -> many to many relationship -> foreign key -> field using dot notation or something similar to dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
pizza.toppings.all()[0].manufacturer.name
```

you can actually do

```
pizza.toppings.first().manufacturer.name
```

This will return the name of the manufacturer of the first topping